# How to prevent row resizing after enter data

Tags: html, css

I am creating a tic tac toe game. Where in initial state I have no data in any button. But whenever any data is entered. The board row resized and if I click all button they go in normal position.

Here I didn't provide all code. Just providing the main problem section. How can I fix it that they will stay all time same position, although there had any value or have one.

```css
.board {
    
}
.board button{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #2d3e50;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button>X</button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the display: flex in your container in order to always keep your buttons centered and together. Flex is always useful

```css
.board {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.board button{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #2d3e50;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button>X</button>
      <button>s</button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button>s</button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class='board'>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... It works.. Actually it was long time I didn't any practice. Thanks one second.

Comment: Keep working, you're doing great!